# Python while loop error with web scraping, same data appearing 5x times

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, while-loop

Before adding in the while loop, the output would be outputting all 100 company data. So I created a while loop to only show the first five companies. Yet now it only shows the first company five times. Any help? Thank you in advance!

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-active/")
    
    class most_active_stock():
        def __init__(self):
            main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tv-data-table__tbody .tv-data-table__row.tv-data-table__stroke.tv-screener-table__result-row")))
            self.companies = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tv-data-table__tbody .tv-data-table__row.tv-data-table__stroke.tv-screener-table__result-row")
            self.result = []
            self.index = 0
    
        def getdata(self):
            for company in self.companies:
                name_short = company.find_element_by_css_selector(".tv-screener__symbol.apply-common-tooltip").text
                name_long = company.find_element_by_css_selector(".tv-screener__description").text
                last = company.find_element_by_css_selector(".tv-data-table__cell.tv-screener-table__cell.tv-screener-table__cell--big.tv-screener-table__cell--with-marker:nth-of-type(2)>span").text
                self.result.append([name_short, name_long, last])
    
        def printdata(self):
            print("MOST ACTIVE STOCKS:", sep='\n')
            for p in self.result:
                while self.index < 5:
                    print(p, sep='\n')
                    self.index += 1
    
    activeStock = most_active_stock()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        activeStock.getdata()
        activeStock.printdata()

    #Output:
    #MOST ACTIVE STOCKS:
    #['GERN', 'GERON CORPORATION', '1.83']
    #['GERN', 'GERON CORPORATION', '1.83']
    #['GERN', 'GERON CORPORATION', '1.83']
    #['GERN', 'GERON CORPORATION', '1.83']
    #['GERN', 'GERON CORPORATION', '1.83']
```

Comment: The company "p" isn't changed in the while-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this part of the code:

```py
def printdata(self):
    print("MOST ACTIVE STOCKS:", sep='\n')
    for p in self.result:
        while self.index < 5:
            print(p, sep='\n')
            self.index += 1
```

So the inner while loop, executes till self.index becomes equal to 5, and in the process it's printing the same 'p' 5 times.

Depending on your how data is organised(looks like it is in the form of a list in `self.result`), you could probably do this:

```py
def printdata(self):
    print("MOST ACTIVE STOCKS:", sep='\n')
    while self.index < 5:
        print(self.result[self.index], sep='\n')
        self.index += 1
```